# combine two sed commands

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed, command-line

How can I combine the following two sed commands.

One loops all files in a directory and removes the first line from them.
The other removes any double quotes " from the start of file lines.

Remove first line of each file

```
for each in `/bin/ls -1`;do sed -i 1d $each;done
```

Beginning of line

```
for each in `/bin/ls -1`;do sed -i 's/^"//g' $each;done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
for each in *; do sed -i.bak 's/^"//g; 1d' "$each"; done
```

Comment: Yeah, creating a backup file is a good practise. +1 for it.

Comment: I borrow you the `.bak` +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use `-e` to perform different `sed` commands in the same line: `sed -e 'command_1' -e 'command_2' ... -e 'command_n'`. You can also use `sed 'command_1; command_2; ...; command_n`.

Let's use the first option and loop through the files:

```
for file in *
do
    sed -i.bak -e '1d' -e 's/^"//' "$file"
done
```

Note also that I use `for file in *`, so that `*` expands to the files in the current directory. This is better than parsing the output of `ls` ([Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is a good read).

Finally, it is a good practise to create a backup file when using `-i`, as anubhava suggests. This way, you are always in the safe side :)

Comment: I was actually going to delete my answer since you answered first and with lot more details +1

Answer (score 4):

You can put them into the same invocation of sed like this:

```
for f in *; do sed -i '1d;s/^"//' "$f"; done
```

As well as combining the two sed commands, I have also used a glob `*` rather than attempting to parse ls, which is never a good idea.

Also, your substitution needn't be global, as it can by definition only apply to each line once, so I removed the `g` modifier as well.

Comment: A bit unfair that others answers have 3 upvotes while yours just 1. I already upvoted, but I would again as it is quite explanatory.

Comment: I guess that's the price I pay for writing the full answer in the first edit, rather than playing the game. Never mind!

Comment: For writing full explanation in first edit +1

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a single commmand in this way:

```
sed -i.bak --separate '1d ; s/^"//' *
```

---

#### Explanation

With `--separate` you're telling sed to treat the files separately, the default is to process them as a long single file but you are using adresses (`1` in the first command) so the default doesn't work.

`'1d ; s/^"//'` just combines the two commands (separated by `;`).

Comment: Didn't know about this gnu `--separate` option +1